# Custom naming a dummy nic on RHEL7.1?

Tags: redhat, rhel7

Is there a way to create a dummy network device named, say, "asdf" on RHEL7.1? In other words, I want to custom name NICs and not have them backed by any physical device. Also which one is more efficient: tap or dummy (since my understanding is that both drivers could do this)?

Comment: Why? Whatcha doin'?

Comment: I want to add them to a bridge (virtual switch) for testing and control their naming for clarity.

Comment: Do you need the dummy interface to be persistent across a reboot? Otherwise a `ip link add asdf type dummy` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this:

Real machine

1. Ensure you have **net.ifnames=1 biosdevname=1** in **grub.cfg** file.
2. Change **/etc/sysconfig/network-script/ifcfg-enX** to **/etc/sysconfig/network-script/ifcfg-dummyX**
3. Ensure that the option **DEVICE=dummyX** in file **/etc/sysconfig/network-script/ifcfg-dummyX** (the option is very importance)

Vmware machine:

I do not test but maybe like this:

1. Change **/etc/sysconfig/network-script/ifcfg-enX** to
   **/etc/sysconfig/network-script/ifcfg-dummyX**
2. Ensure that the option **DEVICE=dummyX** in file
   **/etc/sysconfig/network-script/ifcfg-dummyX** (the option is very importance)